# Import markdown to Onenote

Tags: markdown, microsoft-onenote-2013

I have a lot of notes in markdown that I would like to import to Onenote.
Onenote does a bit of conversion but breaks when `code blocks` are added.
Is there a setting where I can tweak how Onenote interprets markdown ?

Comment: How are you importing the markdown into onenote? Copy and paste? Or actual importing? In what way are code blocks breaking?

Comment: Copy- paste, It shows code blocks as regular text and everything below it is indented  one tab space to the right. with multiple code blocks it gets crazy pretty quickly

Comment: I did an export to Onenote but that exports it as image and its not editable

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄: Why the bounty? Doesn't the answer below work for you and which version of OneNote?

Comment: @harrymc I have stated it in the bounty section: "I am looking for a more recent add-in or for [other] alternative[s] to add mark-down code snippets to OneNote."

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄: Yes, understood, but doesn't NoteNighlight work anymore?

Comment: @harrymc Still haven't tried. As the thread of answers is already relatively old, I am wondering if there are other alternatives. If there isn't and if NiteNighlight works well, will gladly give the bounty to that answer.

Comment: Its last updated version is 3.6 from Apr 14, 2019. That's not too old.

Answer (score 4):

[NoteNighlight](https://github.com/elvirbrk/NoteHighlight2016)!

You have to turn on Markdown in the ribbon.xml config (see bottom of link), open a text editor in admin mode to edit the file, and turn the tag to 'true'.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading the docs always helps, but I wouldn't have stumbled upon this feature (I already had it installed) without your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to automate something with [PanDoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It can accept MarkDown (among other things) and convert it to many other formats, including some that OneNote might understand, like HTML.  It's mostly command-line, so a quick batch file might be in order.

```
pandoc "%~1" -o "temp.html"
pause
del "temp.html"
```

With PanDoc and a batch file like that, you can drag and drop a MarkDown file onto the batch file, and a temp.html file will be generated in the source folder. Open it up, copy/paste the results into OneNote.

There are a list of [OneNote Command-Line Switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-in-Microsoft-Office-OneNote-2007-29468957-1fcc-48b8-8821-00fe5518493a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1), but they're for OneNote 2007, and I couldn't find a similar document for 2010. `/paste` and `/insertdoc` either pasted in raw HTML or nothing at all. Opening the temporary HTML file and copying the rendered results into OneNote works for me, but it's a bit of a hassle.

Another thing about pasting into OneNote is that it has never seemed to respect new lines.  I always have to go back through large pasted documents and add the newlines back so that it's not all one giant paragraph.  I have yet to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to export the MD as HTML? If not, you can use something like [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/) to do so.

If your code blocks are converted to `<pre>` or `<code>` blocks in HTML, you would be able to open the HTML page and copy it into OneNote while keeping the formatting. `<pre>` and `<code>` is dropped, however. You can use some simple CSS to style the content of the tags, which I believe will be copied as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### [onenotegem](http://www.onenotegem.com/a/documents/gem-for-OneNote/Review_Tab/2019/1126/1214.html)

It seems to work as requested

#### [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/)

It converts files from one markup format into another.

#### [The opposite](https://gist.github.com/heardk/ded40b72056cee33abb18f3724e0a580)

Using pandoc you can even do the opposite...

> ```
> ForEach ($result in Get-ChildItem | select Name, BaseName) { pandoc.exe -f docx -t markdown_strict -i $result.Name -o "$($result.BaseName).md" --wrap=none --atx-headers }
> ```

> - `markdown-strict` is the type of Markdown. Other variants exist in the Pandoc documentation
> - `--wrap=none` ensures that text in the new .md files doesn't get wrapped to new lines after 80 characters
> - `--atx-headers` makes headers in the new .md files appear as # h1, ## h2 and so on

Or use scripts from [github](https://github.com/SjoerdV/ConvertOneNote2MarkDown)...

Comment: just saw that onenotegem was created by James Linton. Do you happen to know if it is this [James Linton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Linton_(hacker))?

Comment: Not really.... do you refer to [this one](https://twitter.com/SINON_REBORN?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor)? Always if it is not a _fake_ account... `;-)`.