# markdown feature for Microsoft OneNote 2016

Tags: microsoft-onenote, markdown, microsoft-onenote-2016

**I would like to write my text in OneNote using markdown syntax.**

I'm looking for an add-in or a piece of code to do the job (I understood later that OneNote does not support VBA like Excel does).

I looked at various sources like this in vain. *They are just feature requests on OneNote forums.*

1. [markdown support right from onenote, just like the brand new wordpress addin](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis/suggestions/8088735-markdown-support-right-from-onenote-just-like-the)
2. [Markdown support](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/11075868-markdown-support)

Finally, I came across this one [Gem for OneNote](http://www.onenotegem.com/markdown.html) which says it enables markdown syntax within OneNote 2016 for a fair price. I would like to know if there are any open source/freeware equivalent available before making my payment for this product?

Note:

1. This question is not a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/753058/import-markdown-to-onenote), as this question is an attempt to *import of markdown into OneNote*
2. The question might look like shopping recommendation, in reality it is not. I'm looking for markdown enabler within MS OneNote.

Comment: "I would like to know if there are any open source/freeware" makes it a shopping request.

Comment: What else should I do to look for alternatives? Or how best can I re-word the question

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: [Here is the tool you love](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Productivity-Tools), but I don't know how to compile it. If you can help it's great!

Comment: @Ooker The tool that you are suggesting would convert OneNote format to Markdown. I want to use Markdown while writing in OneNote. Thanks for the link.